# Why are the system tables in MySQL and MariaDB utf8 and not utf8mb4?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I know the general advice is never to use utf8, but instead to use utf8mb4. If that's the advice, then why do the system tables themselves use utf8?

You can see this in the [MariaDB test suite](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/4abb8216a054e14afbeb81e8529e02bab6fa14ac/mysql-test/suite/funcs_1/r/is_columns_mysql_embedded.result#L23), and [and the MySQL test suite](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/124c7ab1d6f914637521fd4463a993aa73403513/mysql-test/suite/funcs_1/r/is_columns_mysql.result); or, by using `SHOW CREATE TABLE mysql.db;`

Answer (score 1):

> By Definitions as per [MySQL Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html):
>
> utf8mb4: A UTF-8 encoding of the Unicode character set using one to
>   four bytes per character.
>
> utf8mb3 : A UTF-8 encoding of the Unicode character set using one to
>   three bytes per character.

Since, **utf8mb3** (also known as **UTF8**) can not store all languages like ***Chinese*** or ***Emoticons***, it is recommended to use **utf8mb4** when it comes to store application data.

For simple example, You want to extend your existing business into China.  if you have used utf8mb4, your application is always ready to adopt your business extension while in case of utf8mb3(UTF-8), you need an ***character set upgrade*** to your application.

While storing system's data MySQL does not store information (supplementary character) which requires utf8mb4, this could be the reason, why MySQL itself is not using utf8mb4.

Comment: So what if I want to create a table with a chinese name?

Comment: Few Chinese character **_does require_** utf8mb4 while few **_does not requires_**. 

For those which requires it, you can't create table with that name.  

For example  requires utf8mb4 hence you can not create a table with this name and will get error "ERROR 1300 (HY000): Invalid utf8 character string: '\xF0\xA1\x9E\xB0'"

But you can create table with 测试 name and it actually does not require utf8mb4.

Hope this clarifies

Answer (score -1):

Pretty much every column in that table is a Y/N field, using the ENUM datatype. Since it has such a consistent and simple dataset there was no reason to use a more complex collation.